# onkeyup Ajax Call and Live Search

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I using a simple ajax script which returns found records using `onkeyup` in input field.

The problem:

Once a record has been returned from call it will stay printed on screen no matter what input is made or if string is latered on field.

Sample:

Lets say the string typed on form field is the word `red`.

red gets printed to screen.

if the letter `i` is added after this been returned, it still shows red.
i need it to show nothing.

Unsure if the problem lies on the readystate.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showResult(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("input1").innerHTML="";
  document.getElementById("input1").style.border="0px";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 && xmlhttp.responseText!='')
    {
    document.getElementById("input1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("input1").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getajax.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to clear the contents of `input1` after every `keyup`?

For that, you would add a call to clear `input1` at the beginning of your function, like this:

```
function showResult(str)
{
    document.getElementById("input1").innerHTML = "";
```

This would clear your element on every `keyup` and then the Ajax would fill it later.

You'd want to cancel any existing Ajax requests at the beginning of the `keyup` handler as well, to make sure any outdated request wouldn't cause the display of the wrong thing.  I'll see if I can paste some code for that later.

Comment: How can I go about "canceling any existing Ajax requests" as you have mentioned. Any good resource or search string i can use?

Answer (score 0):

To cancel any existing Ajax requests, use something like this:

```
function init()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    document.getElementById("ElemInput").onkeyup = function showResult(str)
    {
        if (xmlhttp && xmlhttp.abort) // probably won't work in IE < 7
            xmlhttp.abort(); // cancel AJAX request
        document.getElementById("input1").innerHTML = "";
        if (str.length == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById("input1").style.border = "0px";
            return;
        }
        if (xmlhttp) {} // Do nothing - reuse the object
        else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200) && (xmlhttp.responseText!=''))
            {
                document.getElementById("input1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("input1").style.border = "1px solid #A5ACB2";
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getajax.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", init, false); // for Firefox; for IE, try window.attachEvent
```

This will create a closure where you will reference the same `xmlhttp` object each time.  I haven't tested this extensively, but it should at least point you in the right direction.